# How to change/remove the disabled icon in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I was wondering how I can remove the bootstrap 3 disabled icon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code where you want to have it removed?

Answer (score 3):

for buttons,try this:

```
.btn[disabled] {
    cursor: default !important;
}
```

for other elements,use inspect element and check active class for  `cursor: not-allowed;` and replace it as code above